# Задача на логику. Шоколадка 5 на 8

Tags: логика

> Дана шоколадка 5 на 8. Двое друзей отрезают от шоколадки части и съедают их. Проигрывает тот, кто съест последний кусочек. Придерживаясь какой стратегии можно всегда выигрывать в этой задаче?

Я пришёл к выводу, что нужно каким-то образом привести к квадрату 3 на 3, но как это сделать?

Comment: *отрезают от шоколадки части* Любой формы?

Comment: Можно проводить линии только от одного края к другому, то есть квадратные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предположить, что "отрезают от шоколадки части" означает "ломают плитку по линии на 2 части, и одну из них съедают", то всегда выигрывает первый. Его стратегия - держать плитку квадратной. Т.е. первым делом он делает её 5х5, и в дальнейшем поддерживает квадратной. В итоге когда-то он передаст второму плитку 1х1.